# Vue 3 reusable error handling and handleSubmit in reusable 'useForm' function using the composition api

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In a recent web app we have a lot of forms with the same submit structure:

1. Disable the form and submit button based on an `isSubmitting` variable
2. Validate the input fields (we're using `Yup`)
3. If validation fails: Set `isSubmitting` back to false + set and show `validationErrors` on the input fields
4. If validation succeed: Send post request with form data to api
5. Show general error if api is down or returns an error

I've tried to something using the composition api in vue 3.

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-full flex flex-col justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
            <h1 class="text-3xl text-center text-gray-900">{{ t('sign_in_account', 1) }}</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
            <div class="bg-white py-8 px-4 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
                <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                    <fieldset :disabled="isSubmitting" class="space-y-6">
                        <MessageBox v-if="errors.general" :title="errors.general" :messages="errors.messages" />
                        <Input :label="t('email', 1)" type="text" id="email" v-model="user.email" :error="errors.email" />
                        <Password :label="t('password', 1)" type="password" id="password" v-model="user.password" :error="errors.password" />

                        <div class="text-sm text-right">
                            <router-link class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500" :to="forgotPassword">{{ t('forgot_password', 1) }}</router-link>
                        </div>

                        <SubmitButton class="w-full" :label="t('sign_in', 1)" :submittingLabel="t('sign_in_loader', 1)" :isSubmitting="isSubmitting" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { useStore } from 'vuex';
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

    import useForm from '@/use/useForm';
    import { validateEmail, LoginValidationSchema } from '@/utils/validators';

    export default {
        setup() {
            const store = useStore();
            const { t } = useI18n({ useScope: 'global' });

            const user = ref({
                email: '',
                password: '',
            });

            const { handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors } = useForm(user, LoginValidationSchema, handleLogin);

            async function handleLogin(values) {
                try {
                    return await store.dispatch('auth/login', values);
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.response) {
                        console.log(error.reponse);
                        if (error.response.status == 422) {
                            errors.value = {
                                general: `${t('unable_to_login', 1)}<br /> ${t('fix_and_retry', 1)}`,
                                messages: Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat(),
                            };
                        } else if (error.response.data.message) {
                            errors.value = {
                                general: error.response.data.message,
                            };
                        } else {
                            errors.value = {
                                general: `${t('unknown_error', 1)}<br /> ${t('please_try_agin', 1)}`,
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (error.request) {
                        console.log(error.request);
                        errors.value = {
                            general: `${t('unknown_error', 1)}<br /> ${t('please_try_agin', 1)}`,
                        };
                    } else {
                        errors.value = {
                            general: `${t('unknown_error', 1)}<br /> ${t('please_try_agin', 1)}`,
                        };
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }

            return { t, user, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors };
        },
        computed: {
            forgotPassword() {
                return validateEmail(this.user.email) ? { name: 'forgotPassword', query: { email: this.user.email } } : { name: 'forgotPassword' };
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

**useForm.js**

```
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';

export default function useForm(initialValues, validationSchema, callback) {
    let values = ref(initialValues);
    let isSubmitting = ref(false);
    let errors = ref({});

    async function handleSubmit() {
        try {
            errors.value = {};
            await validationSchema.validate(values.value, { abortEarly: false });
            isSubmitting.value = true;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('In the catch');
            isSubmitting.value = false;

            err.inner.forEach((error) => {
                errors.value = { ...errors.value, [error.path]: error.message };
            });
        }
    }

    watch(isSubmitting, () => {
        if (Object.keys(errors.value).length === 0 && isSubmitting.value) {
            callback(values);
            isSubmitting.value = false;
        } else {
            isSubmitting.value = false;
        }
    });

    return { handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors };
}
```

This is somehow working but I'm missing two things. In `useForm` I want to wait till the callback is done (succeed or failed) to set `isSubmitting` back to false. Is a promise a good way to do this of is there a better way? Secondly I want a reusable way to handle the errors in `Login.vue`. Any suggestion how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question - `try..catch` statements have a third statement called `finally` which always executes `after` the `try` statement block has completed.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

To answer your second question - promises are a great way of handling async logic, including your case when the API you're sending the request to returns an error response, and you can then decide how you're going to handle the UX in such scenario.

I'm not quite clear on what you mean by handle the errors in `Login.vue` in a reusable way, but perhaps you could simple pass in an empty array prop to your `useForm` called `formErrors` and have your `useForm.js` emit an `update:modelValue` event to get two way binding.